# Analytic function giving random results but only when querying through view

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a moving average filter through a column of values using the formula:

`new_values - (AVG(old_values) OVER (PARTITION BY category, subcategory ORDER BY date BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING))`

I've tested the script through the Query editor, all is well and I'm getting correct results. However, after I have saved and queried it through a view, two rows calculated at the top and bottom of the columns are inconsistent (the ones where the filter is overlapping the edges). Every time I run the query they change, and not by a little.

```
date        new_values  old_values  query_editor  view   also_view  again_view
2020-01-01  0.87        0.85        0.02          0.082  0.074      0.052 
2020-01-02  0.85        0.82        -0.0025       0.032  0.026      0.018
2020-01-03  0.92        0.88        0.038         0.038  0.038      0.038
2020-01-04  0.82        0.86        -0.06         -0.06  -0.06      -0.06
2020-01-05  0.94        1.0         0.056         0.056  0.056      0.056
```

Any indication on what might be causing this?

EDIT: (See comment below.) If others are wondering, what was happening was that null rows (ordered randomly with each query) existed in the dataset and was contributing to the window function. E.g.

```
date        new_values  old_values  query_editor  view   also_view  again_view
null        null        0.99  <- These would be read and ordered randomly
null        null        0.12  <- giving a varied output.      
2020-01-01  0.87        0.85        0.02          0.082  0.074      0.052 
2020-01-02  0.85        0.82        -0.0025       0.032  0.026      0.018
2020-01-03  0.92        0.88        0.038         0.038  0.038      0.038
2020-01-04  0.82        0.86        -0.06         -0.06  -0.06      -0.06
2020-01-05  0.94        1.0         0.056         0.056  0.056      0.056
```

To stop this from happening, slot in a case statement:

`new_values - (AVG(CASE WHEN new_values IS NOT NULL THEN old_values ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY category, subcategory ORDER BY date BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING))`

Comment: Can you post the source data from your table and the view as well as the outputs? So I can investigate where they are different and why.

Comment: I've managed to suss out what the problem was. Our dataset contained null dates and null values from dates that are yet to happen, however nearly all of these null rows contain an "old_value". Although the queries are identical, when we queried this through a view, the rows that contained null would be ordered inconsistently and we would read from these null rows that were randomly ordered on both ends of our column. Why this only happened when queried from view I don't know, I'm just happy our statistics are no longer hilariously erratic.